# Dockerfile ENV available in the .env file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an ENV set in `Dockerfile`:

```
...
ENV APP_HOME=/myapp
...
```

I also have a `.env` file.:

```
DATA_DIR=$APP_HOME/data
```

If I run the image with the env file:

```
docker run --env-file .env app_image
```

and echo the env variables in the shell(bash),

```
$ echo $DATA_DIR

$APP_HOME/data
```

I was expecting:

```
/myapp/data
```

My question is, how can I pass the ENV set during the docker build to the .env file?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how can I pass the ENV set during the docker build to
>   the .env file?

The short answer is that it is not possible.

The reason is that `.env` will not execute any bash command or take in any other external environment variables and hence the `docker run` command will just pass in the literal string.

As a result, you will see the value of `$APP_HOME/data`